# Remove duplicate values array ionic3

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to remove duplicate values in the storage array in Ionic3

```
this.storage.get('thestations').then((val) => { 

           for(let i =0;i<val.length;i++){
            if(this.newarray.indexOf(this.newarray) == -1) {
            this.newarray.push(val[i]);
            } 
                console.log(newarray);

      });
```

But it still return duplicates values

Comment: What is format of val object?

Comment: Please update the question with your array.

Comment: You are testing whether one of the items in newarray matches the entire newarray, which I doubt is your goal.

Answer (score 4):

**Using Set**

```
var val = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Mango"];
var newarray =  Array.from(new Set(val));
```

**check here using Reduce**

```
var val = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Mango"];
var newarray = val.reduce(function(res, ele) {
    if(res.indexOf(ele)==-1)
       res.push(ele);
return res;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 3):

**One-liner:** `[...new Set(["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Mango"])]`

```
this.storage.get('thestations').then(val => {  
  console.log('with duplicates',val);   
  console.log('without duplicates',[...new Set(val)]);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, you solved your problem or not, but I have one of the most efficient answer for you.

Javascript provides **lodash** library for us.
For full documentation, please visit [Lodash Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11)

Lodash provides us with thousands of built-in functions like filter, unique, isEqual and lots more.

**Step 1:**
You just need to install the npm package of lodash by following command.

> npm install lodash --save

**Step 2:**
Import the dependency in your component file.

```
import * as lodash from 'lodash';
```

**Step 3:**
Now consider you have array named as abcArr = [5,10, 8, 11, 10, 8];
And you want to ignore all the repeated numbers.

Use the following code to get the expected output.

```
let abcArr = [5,10, 8, 11, 10, 8];
let uniqueArr = []; 
uniqueArr = lodash.uniqWith(abcArr, lodash.isEqual);
```

Hence you will get your expected solution like above. Hope so, it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use function like below

```
var val = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Mango"];
var newarray = [];

for(let i=0; i < val.length; i++)
{
    if(newarray.indexOf(val[i]) == -1)
        newarray.push(val[i]);
}
console.log(newarray);

</script>
```

You have to change `val` variable as per your requirement.